# Dockerfile - add file from a windows directory in the .NET Core Web API

Tags: windows, file, .net-core, dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core Web API with a Dockerfile and I want in the Dockerfile, from my Windows host container current user directory to copy a file to the docker container.

Basically, I've tried the following command:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ADD C:/Users/MyUser/custom_directory/myfile /root/other_directory/myfile
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApi.dll"]
```

But I get the following error:

```
Service 'myservice' failed to build: lstat C:/Users/MyUser/custom_directory/myfile: no such file or directory
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can ADD (copy) only files from a source directory. In this case Visual Studio project directory.

Copy myfile to project directory and add a new line "myfile" to `.dockerignore` file. Default VS dockerignore file is configured to ignore all files except `obj/Docker/publish/*` and `obj/Docker/empty/`.

For better understanding read this:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add